# How to call actionresult from the view using button(submit)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call actionresult in my controller. But it doesn't call it from the view.

I have tried using `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("action", "controller")'">` but it doesn't even enter the function.

My view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("WritePost", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype 
= "Multipart/form-data" }))
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
<h4>Skriv inlägg</h4>
<hr />
<div>
@{Html.RenderAction("_CategoryPartialView", "Category");}
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryId)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
"control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
@class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = 
"text-danger" })
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
"control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, 10, 100, new { @class = 
"form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = 
"text-danger" })
</div>

<input type="file" name="file" />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File)

</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

<input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
```

My Controller

```
public ActionResult EmailWhenPost()
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var senderEmail = new MailAddress("ExampleMail@gmail.com");
            var receiverEmail = new MailAddress("ExampleMail2@gmail.com");
            var password = "Pass";
            var subject = "New Post";
            var body = "Message";
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail.Address, password)
            };
            using (var mess = new MailMessage(senderEmail, receiverEmail)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {

                smtp.Send(mess);
            }
            return View();
        }
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "Some Error";
    }
    return View();
}
```

I want to use the function to send an email when a post is sent. It should not return a view, just trigger the function.

Comment: Your controller has the `[HttpPost]` decorator?

Comment: You're not even calling the same function as shown in the description

Comment: Where is your attempt to use `Url.Action`? We need to see this to advise on it.

Comment: The view *displays* the data returned as an `ActionResult` from a controller action. It doesn't produce that ActionResult. Your *form* should call the correct action. Your action though is named `EmailWhenPost` but your view code calls *WritePost* `Html.BeginForm("WritePost",`

Comment: Yes i got the [HttpPost]. Didn't make it in the code.

I use html.beginform("Writepost") so you cant post something. But i also want to call the function when you press the send button.

Comment: @Thunders if you want to know what's getting called use the browser's Developer Tools or Fiddler to see the actual request sent in the Network tab. I suspect you'll see that the *wrong* URL is called when you click the submit button

Comment: @AndyG
<input type="submit"  value="Send" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("EmailWhenPost", "SendEmail")'"/>

ControllerName = SendEmailController

Comment: With that you are ignoring the fact that you have a form and a submit button, and the default behaviour is to submit the form. Why do you need a click event anyway, you still need to post all the data back via a form submission.

Comment: The name of your action `EmailWhenPost` suggests that you just want a form, and a post action to process the data; then, if the data is successfully processed, send an email confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the correct function MyController/EmailWhenPost (please rename this to SendEmail, and add an attribute of [HttpPost] and then in the controller action just return void (a controller method that returns void will produce an EmptyResult.)

[First read this article about general rounting in ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

[Then read this msdn article about producing empty results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695917.aspx)

Comment: The problem is that the action itself is never called.

Comment: He's not even calling the correct function. That's the main issue